# Engine knocking

Tags: engine

I have a 2013 Hyundai sante fe sport (base). Engine started knocking due to it burning all the oil within 5k miles ( I understand that’s a problem). Put oil in it and still knocking. Took the engine apart everything looks good I could not find any issues inside of it. Could it be the variable valve timing solenoid for the exhaust? I replaced the intake one. I was wondering if that could cause the knock and shut off

Comment: You took the engine apart and everything looks good... did you measure the bearings etc to check all the tolerances? If you did not then the problem may still be there.

Comment: you say the engine burned all the oil,did you run the engine out of oil?

Comment: Was the knocking coming from the top or bottom of the engine?

Comment: Got it from the dealership about 6 months ago and two days ago the oil change light came on hadn’t had time to change it yet and then it’s pretty much shut down changed both vvt solenoids and now it’s just a tick instead of a knock. Pretty sure it was bottom and yes I checked all of it the lobes had some wear on the ends but that was it. It seems driveable right now. Cranked it up idles smooth just with a tick